# Factoring algebraic expressions- basic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I would like to know the process of factoring this algebraic expression:
1) $64a^6+16a^3+1$

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

set $$a^3=t$$ and factor $$64t^2+16t+1$$

Comment: how do you arrive at this answer: (2a+1)^2(4a^2-2a+1)^2

Comment: $$64t^2+16t+1=64(t+\frac{1}{8})^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = a^3$.  Then 
$$64a^6 + 16a^3 + 1 = 64u^2 + 16u + 1 = (8u + 1)^2 = (8a^3 + 1)^2$$
Now use the sum of cubes formula 
$$x^3 + y^3 = (x + y)(x^2 - xy + y^2)$$ 
to factor the term inside the parentheses.